# callback function req. and res

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having trouble to understand why my callback function needs 2 parameters, i.e. one for the request and one for the response?

For instance i bind a callback function to my server:

```
server.on("request", doThis(req, resp));
```

In my opinion he needs only one parameter (req for example here) to store the `req` information (GET, POST, url, etc.). Why does he need a second for response? I write the information in resp. (i.e. the server, so my other scripts) and not the client.

Every time a request is coming in, the callback function is invoked and so the `req` parameter is set. Am i wrong? But why do I need the response parameter? My server needs it when he is responding but not when I'm reading/saving the request informations?

Comment: If you aren't using the `resp` argument, you can leave it off the definition of your callback.  It will still be passed to the callback, but you can leave it out if you aren't using it.  You can only do this because it's the last argument.

Comment: FYI, `server.on("request", doThis(req, resp));` is probably not right.  You probably mean `server.on("request", doThis);`

Comment: Yes, you're right. ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Response parameter is what's generally used to send back a response.

A request comes in, you get the request's data in the `req` (first) param and you then use the `res` (second) param to send back a response like:

```
server.on('message', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello your ip is: ' + req.client.ip);
})
```

This is all dependant on your framework but in **expressjs** this is how it works (more or less).

To answer your question, you don't need it - you can simply not issue it as a parameter (although it will still be accessible) if you don't plan on responding (which is weird and quite uncommon)

```
server.on('message', function(req){
    console.log('someone requested "message"')
})
```

Generally speaking, you would always send back a response although the end user might never visually see it, it's just to confirm that the action has been completed successfully.

```
server.on('save', function(req, res){
    saveFile(req.file)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

Additionally, you could check if the process completed successfully - if it did you'd send back a success message, otherwise send back an error message.

```
server.on('save', function(req, res){
    saveFile(req.file, function(error){
        if(error) res.sendStatus(500)
        res.sendStatus(200)
    })
})
```

Comment: Ah ok, but you say when i omit the `res` i couldn't response to the client. That's what i don't understand. You said yourself that the requested data is saved in the `req` parameter. But what is stored in this step in the `res` variable? Nothing?

When there's nothing stored then i could answer to the client without this `res` object, all what i need is stored in the `req` parameter. But yes, of course i want to respond to the client. ;)

Comment: Run `console.log(res)`, it's mostly functions (`send`, `sendStatus` ...), a lot of people tend to define `res.locals` prior to routing which comes in handy and you might find interesting.